# Grouping extension methods

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, .net-4.5, extension-methods

I am working with `.NET 4.5`, `VS2013` and `Selenium`.

I am writing selenium tests for products that are somewhat similar in their page flow structure and field structure.

To set values to the fields I am using extension methods on `IWebDriver`

Example:

```
    private void WillsCustomerDetail(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        driver.WillsSetMainCustomerTitle("Dr");
        driver.WillsSetMainCustomerGender("Male");
        driver.WillsSetMainCustomerName("Liufa");
        driver.WillsSetMainCustomerSurname("Afuil");
        driver.WillsSetMainCustomerDateOfBirth(new DateTime(1955, 12, 26));
        ...
   }

    public static IWebElement WillsSetMainCustomerName(this IWebDriver driver, string value)
    {
        return driver.SetText(value, WillsElements.CustomerDetails.MainCustomer.Firstname);
    }

    public static IWebElement SetText(this IWebDriver driver, string value, string selector)
    {
        var element = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(selector));
        element.SendKeys(value);
        return element;
    }

    public static class WillsElements
    {
        public static class CustomerDetails
        {
            public static class MainCustomer
            {
                public static string Title
                {
                    get { return "#Customers-0--Title"; }
                }
            ...
            }
         }
     }
```

What I am having issue is my method naming

`WillsSetMainCustomerTitle` - In reality is concatenation of
Wills - product (web journey),
MainCustomer - partial page,
Title - field,

and for next product I will have `LpaSetMainCustomerName` and most of other fields that make it a huge mess.

What I would like to have is

```
driver.Wills.MainCustomer.SetTitle("Dr");
```

as an extension method

**Is there a way of achieving grouped extension methods? (Or getting something similar that would allow nice grouping while still having extension methods).**

Comment: Why can't you extend the type of `MainCustomer`?

Comment: What are the fields of `WillsElements`?

Comment: @haim770 I could, but then I would have to pass `IWebDriver` into each call `Wills.MainCustomer.SetTitle(driver, "Dr"); ` or I have misinterpreted your question?

Comment: @Codor WillsElements is static class with more static classes inside that provides me with nice structure to hold css selectors to all usable elements on pages. It's convenience thing. There are quite a few as you can imagine one per selectable element. Few more `    public static class WillsElements
    {
        public static class Index
        {
            public static string WillsQuoteType
            {
                get { return "#WillsQuoteType"; }
            }

            public static string MaritalStatus
            {
                get { return "#MaritalStatus"; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not directly possible to group extension methods like that.

In the example

```
driver.Wills.MainCustomer.SetTitle("Dr");
```

you can make `Wills` and `MainCustomer` methods that each return a specialized type. The next level (`MainCustomer` and `SetTitle`) of drilling in can then key off of those types. Search for "fluent style" to see what I mean. I don't recommend this here. It creates a ton of work to set up just to get that little period character where you want it.

You also could wrap the driver:

```
new WillsDriver(driver)
 .MainCustomer
 .Title = "Dr";
```

Again, you have to write all those classes and members.

May I suggest the following naming convention:

```
Wills_MainCustomer_SetTitle
```

A very simple solution to make this more readable.

If the body of those methods is always very similar consider using a T4 template to generate all possible cases of these methods.

Comment: I haven't thought of wrapping the driver. Sir you are a genius! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are wondering what have I ended up with.

```
    [Test]
    [TestCaseSource("WillsTestData")]
    public void WillsTest(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(WillsNavigation.Index);
        var willsDriver = new WillsDriver(driver);
        this.WillsCustomerDetail(willsDriver);
        ...
    }

    private void WillsCustomerDetail(WillsDriver driver)
    {
        driver.CustomerDetail.MainCustomer.Title = "Dr";
        driver.CustomerDetail.MainCustomer.Gender = "Male";
        driver.CustomerDetail.MainCustomer.Name = "Liufa";
        driver.CustomerDetail.MainCustomer.Surname = "Afuil";
        driver.CustomerDetail.MainCustomer.DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1955, 12, 26);
        ...
        driver.CustomerDetail.ClickContinue();
    }

public class WillsDriver
{
    public WillsDriver(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        this.Driver = driver;
        this.Index = new IndexClass(driver);
        this.Quote = new QuoteClass(driver);
        this.CustomerDetail = new CustomerDetailsClass(driver);
    }

    public CustomerDetailsClass CustomerDetail { get; private set; }
    public IndexClass Index { get; private set; }
    public QuoteClass Quote { get; private set; }
    public IWebDriver Driver { get; set; }
    ....

    public class CustomerDetailsClass
    {
        public CustomerDetailsClass(IWebDriver driver)
        {
            this.Driver = driver;
            this.MainCustomer = new MainCustomerClass(driver);
            this.SecondCustomer = new SecondCustomerClass(driver);
        }

        public IWebDriver Driver { get; set; }

        public MainCustomerClass MainCustomer { get; private set; }

        public SecondCustomerClass SecondCustomer { get; private set; }
        ....
        public class MainCustomerClass
        {
            public MainCustomerClass(IWebDriver driver)
            {
                this.Driver = driver;
            }

            public IWebDriver Driver { get; set; }

            public string Title
            {
                set
                {
                    this.Driver.SetDropDown(value, WillsElements.CustomerDetails.MainCustomer.Title);
                    if (value == "Dr") Thread.Sleep(700);
                }
            }
       ....
      }
 }

public class WillsElements
{
    public static class CustomerDetails
    {
        public static class MainCustomer
        {
            public static string Title
            {
                get { return "#Customers-0--Title"; }
            }

            public static string Gender
            {
                get { return "#Customers-0--GenderSection-Gender"; }
            }

            public static string Firstname
            {
                get { return "#Customers-0--Firstname"; }
            }
    ....
    }
}

public static class SetWillElement
{
    public static IWebElement SetDropDown(this IWebDriver driver, string value, string selector)
    {
        var element = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(selector));
        var select = new SelectElement(element);
        select.SelectByText(value);
        return element;
    }

    public static string YesNoToCssSelector(this string name, string value)
    {
        return string.Format("{0}[value='{1}']", name, value == "Yes" ? "True" : "False");
    }

    public static IWebElement ClickButton(this IWebDriver driver, string selector)
    {
        var element = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(selector));
        element.Click();
        return element;
    }

    public static IWebElement SetRadio(this IWebDriver driver, string value, string selector)
    {
        var element = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(selector));
        ((IJavaScriptExecutor) driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].checked = true;", element);
        return element;
    }

    public static IWebElement SetText(this IWebDriver driver, string value, string selector)
    {
        var element = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(selector));
        element.SendKeys(value);
        return element;
    }
}
```

I should probably pull `WillsElements` into `WillsDriver` class, this would make it even neater.